# "Coming soon" or "coming next" or…?

Tags: phrase-choice

If you are working on something that will take some time to be completed (for example two or three months), how would you announce that? I think that "coming soon" is not well suited. Maybe "coming next"?

Comment: It depends on how the "two or three months" period is perceived in the context of the overall process.  It can be "soon" if everything else is expected to appear within a year or two.  Also, if you expect to present nothing else in the meantime, then "next" is OK.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding using the specific time frame or even a more specific but still general one like "In a few months". Can you please explain exactly how you plan to use the phrase?

Answer (score 1):

If X is coming *soon*, something could come before X, even though by saying *soon* you are saying not much time will pass before X comes.

If X is coming *next*, nothing else should come before X.  A long time (an interval not considered soon) could pass before X comes.